# jquery is resetting my div content

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the content of div using jquery. but the content flashes and resets the div. i cannot use `return false;` because there is another button for post text field value. i want to keep the changes of div. here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <form id="form" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="gname" id="gname"/></br>
            <button id="btn">Set</button>
            <button id="nbtn">View</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="outp">

    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $("#btn").click(function(event) {
        $.post("send.php", {
            named: $("#gname").val()}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });

</script>

<script>
    $("#nbtn").click(function(e) {

        $("#outp").html("<?php include './view.php'; ?>");

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Fix your </br> element first - should be <br />

Comment: In you code, $("#outp").html("<p>My new text</p>"); check and see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not jQuery; it's that your form is being posted. So your change is made, but then the form is posted and the page is refreshed from the server.

The default type of `button` elements is `"submit"`. To make one or both of those buttons just a button, use `type="button"`.

Alternately, if you want to allow the form to be used when JavaScript is disabled (e.g., allow it to be posted normally), leave the buttons as submit buttons but prevent form submission using JavaScript. E.g.:

```
$("#form").submit(false); // Prevents the form being submitted in the normal way.
```

Comment: @user3383167: :-) That's another way to go, if you don't need a fallback for JavaScript-disabled browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Any buttons inside a form are considered `submit` buttons.

So you need to add `event.preventDefault()` to your `.click` code.

Also, why are your scripts outside `body` section?

Answer (score -1):

## You can try with ajax and catch success and error:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var named: $("#gname").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'send.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {param1: 'value1'},
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("Post success"+data);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("Post error"+data);
    });     
});
```